# Why use Array#to_enum when Array already is an Enumerable?

Tags: ruby, arrays

As far as I understand the Array class already mixes in the Enumerable module.

If that's so, why isn't there `[:example].next`?

Why do I need to make it `[:example].to_enum.next`?

Comment: Because the method `next` is defined on the class `Enumerator` and not `Array`. Array mixes in Enumerable which makes the conversation to `Enumerator` possible in the first place.

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863044/what-is-the-advantage-of-creating-an-enumerable-object-using-to-enum-in-ruby)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [`Enumerable` module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) is different from the [`Enumerator` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html).

Being "Enumerable" means that the class gets a bunch of freebie methods that create "Enumerators".  Compare to Java's [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interfaces.

Comment: Enumberable, Enumerator, I overlooked that! now everything makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`to_enum` has nothing to do with `Enumerable`, it returns an `Enumerator`. `Array` doesn't have a `next` method because `next` is an `Enumerator` method, not an `Enumerable` method.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the difference between Enumerable and Enumerator!

Comment: @JanDvorak `to_enum` is a method of `Object`