# Ruby: Understanding .to_enum better

Tags: ruby, enums, enumeration

I have been reading this:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Enumerator.html

I am trying to understand why someone would use `.to_enum`, I mean how is that different than just an array? I see :scan was passed into it, but what other arguments can you pass into it?

Why not just use .scan in the case below?  Any advice on how to understand `.to_enum` better?

```
"Hello, world!".scan(/\w+/)                     #=> ["Hello", "world"]
"Hello, world!".to_enum(:scan, /\w+/).to_a      #=> ["Hello", "world"]
"Hello, world!".to_enum(:scan).each(/\w+/).to_a #=> ["Hello", "world"]
```

Comment: that `each` is doing nothing, BTW

Comment: Take a look at this answer, maybe it would be helpful for understanding the purpose of this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867225/4453714

Comment: "I mean how is that different than just an array?" – Consider the difference between the memory usage of an array of all prime numbers and an enumerator of all prime numbers.

Comment: An array is very mutable, which is not always desirable. A simple `.to_enum` makes it immutable (or at least harder to mutate).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are, necessarily, constructs that are *in memory*. An array with a a lot of entries takes up a lot of memory.

To put this in context, here's an example, finding all the "palindromic" numbers between 1 and 1,000,000:

```
# Create a large array of the numbers to search through
numbers = (1..1000000).to_a

# Filter to find palindromes
numbers.select do |i|
  is = i.to_s
  is == is.reverse
end
```

Even though there's only 1998 such numbers, the entire array of a million needs to be created, then sifted through, then kept around until garbage collected.

An enumerator doesn't necessarily take up any memory at all, not in a consequential way. This is way more efficient:

```rb
# Uses an enumerator instead
numbers = (1..1000000).to_enum

# Filtering code looks identical, but behaves differently
numbers.select do |i|
  is = i.to_s
  is == is.reverse
end
```

You can even take this a step further by making a custom Enumerator:

```rb
palindromes = Enumerator.new do |y|
  1000000.times do |i|
    is = (i + 1).to_s

    y << i if (is == is.reverse)
  end
end
```

This one doesn't even bother with filtering, it just emits *only* palindromic numbers.

Enumerators can also do other things like be *infinite* in length, whereas arrays are necessarily finite. An infinite enumerator can be useful when you want to filter and take the first *N* matching entries, like in this case:

```rb
# Open-ended range, new in Ruby 2.6. Don't call .to_a on this!
numbers = (1..).to_enum

numbers.lazy.select do |i|
  is = i.to_s
  is == is.reverse
end.take(1000).to_a
```

Using `.lazy` here means it does the `select`, then filters through `take` with each entry until the `take` method is happy. If you remove the `lazy` it will try and evaluate each stage of this to completion, which on an infinite enumerator never happens.